# What do you lose if you rewrite the Dirac equation in terms of $\mid\Psi\mid^{2}=\Phi$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, dirac-equation, spinors

Taking a look at the Dirac equation (taking $\hbar$ to be unity):

$$\bar{\Psi}(i\gamma^{a}e_{a}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\Psi=0$$

The operator is Hermitian and and hence we may rewrite it as:

$$\Psi(i\gamma^{a}e_{a}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\bar{\Psi}=0$$

Though the bar here denotes the Dirac adjoint, I believe it's still valid (if not we can pull $\gamma^{0} out of \bar{\Psi})$. I find it useful to remember that all physically measurable information comes from considering expectation values, so I like writing it as:

$$\intop_{allspace}\bar{\Psi}(i\gamma^{a}e_{a}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\Psi d^{3}x=0$$

This is just personal “taste” yet it seems to encode all pertinent information regarding the Dirac equation (not counting normalization which is another constraint). We can put the first two equations together as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\bar{\Psi}(i\gamma^{a}e_{a}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu})\Psi+\left\{ (i\gamma^{a}e_{a}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu})\bar{\Psi}\right\} \Psi\right]-m\Psi\bar{\Psi}=0$$

Maybe I messed something simple up, but something like that should be achievable. At this point, we may as well write:

$$(i\gamma^{a}e_{a}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-2m)\mid\Psi\mid^{2}=0$$

Then what purpose does that serve, let's just use a scalar such that: $\mid\Psi\mid^{2}=\Phi$.

$$(i\gamma^{a}e_{a}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-2m)\Phi=0$$

This seems to encode all the same physical information as the Initial Dirac equation, though clearly the solutions for a given problem will be of another “flavor”.

I'm wondering here, just what information have we lost?, (I'm sure it's something, maybe the negative energy solutions?)

**EDIT:**

It was really late when I asked this and so I confused quite a bit of notation. I plan on coming back to rewrite this later (in a manner not invalidating the comments and answer below).

Comment: Some of your equations look pretty strange. For example in second equation you have your Dirac operator acting on $\bar \Psi$ from the left which is not really how this equation is usually written. Remember that $\Psi$ is not a number but rather a column vector of complex numbers. In this (usual) notation $\bar \psi \psi$ is a number but $\psi \bar \psi$ is a spinorial matrix instead. Note also that notation $\bar \psi \psi = | \psi|^2$ is really confusing because $\bar \psi \psi$ is not positive in general.

Comment: Also, remember that such operators are actually operator-valued distributions and they have to first be integrated against some functions to become actual operators.

Comment: @Blazej apologies, maybe I'm wrong, but I thought that the Inner product of the Dirac wavefunction with itself was always positive definite, and this is what had made it better than it's predecessors. I could ask the same question about the Schrodinger equation, though, I'm really just trying to use properties off Hermitian operators to play at rewriting equations

Comment: @GennaroTedesco  That is precisely why I put the bit in the question about the integral

Comment: @R.Rankin Written in that way that integral makes no sense: you have to first specify the class of functions you are integrating upon and then the states those operators act on.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco  Isn't the integrand a scalar in any case? One could say that integral is just the Dirac action integral (without the time integral outside it all).

Comment: @R.Rankin It becomes a scalar after you have made proper sense of it. From $\Psi$ you have to construct $\Psi(f) = \int dx f(x) \Psi(x)$ first, for some $f$: this will be an operator: then such operator acts on some vectors in some space and then the gamma matrices act eventually thereupon. Likewise $\Psi^{\dagger}$ is the adjoint of such functional, not just a complex number.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco  Could you kindly lead me to a treatise on when Dirac did that in deriving the equation bearing his name?

Comment: Gennaro Tedesco I believe OP means c-number Dirac equation here and the only operator here is the Dirac operator $i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} - m$.

Comment: @Blazej yes I'm only looking at the non QFT version hence the tag quantum mechanics rather than quantum field theory

Comment: @Blazej  Note that I defined $\psi$ bar as the dirac adjoint so it must be positive definite.

Comment: No, it isn't. $\psi^{\dagger} \psi$ is positive, while in $\bar \psi \psi = \psi^{\dagger} \gamma^0 \psi$ there is matrix $\gamma^0$ which is not positive. If you want explicit example, find a spinor which is an eigenvector of $\gamma^0$ to eigenvalue $-1$. Then $\bar \psi \psi = - \psi^{\dagger} \psi <0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I will try to formalise a little the objects that define the theory: of course many more mathematical details must be filled, so do not take this as exhaustive.

1. We assume, to start with, the existence of a Dirac algebra of operators $\gamma^{\mu}$ satisfying the below (anti)-commutation relations 
   $$
   \lbrace\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\rbrace = 2g^{\mu\nu}\mathbf{1}
   $$
   for some metric $g$. Once so, one starts looking for *representations* of such algebra over some space. Once can show that the fields, as operator valued distributions, defined by $f\mapsto B(f)$ such that
   $$
   B(f)^{\dagger} = B(\Gamma f)\qquad 
   $$
   $$
   \big{\lbrace} B(f), B(g)\big{\rbrace} = \sigma(\Gamma f,g)\mathbf{1}
   $$
   for some unitary involution $\Gamma$ and some scalar product $\sigma$ (that the above metric $g$ comes from) is a good representation of the initial Dirac algebra.
2. Given the above one defines the dynamics as the set of all fields fulfilling the following equation of motion
   $$
   \Psi^{\dagger}(i\partial_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}-m)\Psi = 0
   $$
   whose solution is certain families of objects $\Psi$ whose precise sense in operator terms is given by the aforementioned construction.
3. Once we are equipped with the solution of the equation of motion (some special $\Psi$) then we define correlation functions thereof, namely we postulate that we have knowledge (that can be derived even by means of arguments of symmetries and invariances) of
   $$
   \omega_0\big(B(f)B(g)\big) = (\Gamma f, P g)
   $$
   where $\omega_0$ is a state of the system and $P$ is some special (projection) operator. Higher order correlation functions can be derived from the 2-point function as products of sums thereof (Wick's theorem).
4. It can be shown that the knowledge of the correlation functions is, under some suitable assumptions, sufficient to reconstruct the whole theory in terms of states, operators and scattering amplitudes.

Of course there is much more to be filled in, the above is just a short draft of how one goes around to make sense of the objects in QFT. One would have to prove that all the operators and their representations are bounded, well defined on some domains and that their commutation relations are physically meaningful, namely that causality is preserved for space-like intervals.

---

#### References

1. [Local Quantum Physics](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540614517), Rudolf Haag.
2. [Mathematical Theory of Quantum Fields](https://www.amazon.de/Mathematical-Quantum-International-Monographs-Physics/dp/0199566402), Huzihiro Araki.

Comment: +1 I appreciate that, but I purposely didn't tag this as quantum field theory because its just relativistic quantum mechanics. Everything in the question is prior to second quantization.

Comment: I am rather confused about the first point. You seem to be talking about representation of canonical commutation relations rather than Dirac algenra itself. The latter is represented on bispinor space which is much simpler object,

Comment: I agree, I have somehow hidden that the $\Psi$ acting on their representation give a full representation of the initial Dirac algebra, in turn. However, I disagree that the bispinor space is a "much simpler" object: it isn't, if you want to properly define and construct it (it isn't just a set of vectors with 4 components) because of the way the $\Psi$ must act on it giving back operator valued distributions again (to make sense with the original Dirac equation).